# Como colocar valor default em campo time no mysql?

Tags: mysql, time

Procurei na web mas não achei nada especifico para campo time no mysql, só date e timestamp, estou criando um campo "hora_emissao" do tipo "time", pois quero armazenar somente a hora nesse campo, a linha seria o seguinte:

```
ADD COLUMN `hora_emissao`  time NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME;
```

Mas recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIME

Se dermos o comando: SELECT CURRENT_TIME vemos que ele mostra a hora do servidor, ou seja current_time existe.

Qual a forma correta de criar um campo time com valor default no mysql?

Obs.: Eu posso usar trigger ou outro tipo de campo, mas a ideia é simplificar usando a função default e usar um campo time mesmo, já que preciso somente da hora, se existisse como deixar default a hora do servidor seria ótimo.

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso

Comment: tente  ADD COLUMN `hora_emissao`  time NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURTIME(); fonte https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time

Comment: Qual é a versão do MySQL?

Comment: Versao do MySQL 5.7.9

Comment: Tentou colocar entre parênteses: (CURRENT_TIME)?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar o campo como `TIMESTAMP` e na hora de usá-lo, formatar para pegar apenas a hora.

Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE `suaTabela` (
  `datahora` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)
```

Na hora de usar:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datahora,"%H:%i:%s") AS hora FROM suaTabela
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie o seu campo hora_emissao como datetime, e na query de insert, utilize a funçao current_timestamp().

Entao ficaria

Insert INTO tabela (hora_emissao) values(current_timestamp());

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma TRIGGER para inseri a hora atual no seu campo:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER horaatual BEFORE INSERT ON TIME
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       SET NEW.hora=CURTIME();
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```